# CSS Slider in iMac/device frame

Tags: html, css, slider

Does anybody know any plugins or step-by-step guides on how I can create a slider in an iMac frame? I've used a Device Mockup plugin (https://devicemockupswp.com/gallery-slider/) but it doesn't have a pagination option as I want my sites users to be able to view the slides one by one.

Kinda like this website's https://www.grab.com/my/

If anybody knows any plugins or tutorials that can help that would be groovy. I'm most comfortable around html and css if that helps!

Answer (score 0):

Try [swiper](http://idangero.us/swiper/)

Checkout the [demos](http://idangero.us/swiper/demos/) page

Comment: I couldn't manage to see an example of swiper including a slider within an imac border like this http://purecssapple.com/ (see examples).

Comment: It can be done inside a container. And your container is? (an IMac).
Just create a div container with a background image(IMac) then add padding and stuff